# Number of dataset files incorrect

Tags: crawlee

I am following this [article](https://crawlee.dev/docs/examples/add-data-to-dataset). The number of files generated are sometimes < 3.  I am expecting 000000001.json, 000000002.json and 000000003.json files to be generated in the storage/datasets/default

But, sometimes there are 1 or 2 files generated.

I removed the storage folder and run. I still get 1-2 files only some times.

```
import { Dataset, CheerioCrawler } from 'crawlee';

const crawler = new CheerioCrawler({
    // Function called for each URL
    async requestHandler({ request, body }) {
        // Save data to default dataset
        await Dataset.pushData({
            url: request.url,
            html: body,
        });
    },
});

await crawler.addRequests([
    'http://www.example.com/page-1',
    'http://www.example.com/page-2',
    'http://www.example.com/page-3',
]);

// Run the crawler
await crawler.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

If-when request fails (i.e. on timeout), handler not reached and therefore data is not inserted, so it will be as you described: sometimes you getting less dataset items, please check (logs) if its the case.